# Lebesgue-Integral as Riemann-Integral

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

This is a rather basic question on parts of the Lebesgue-Integral formula. Intuitively it should be clear, but I am searching for a mathematical explanation.

If $f: (\Omega, \mathcal{A}) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}, \mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ is a measurable function and $\mu$ a measure on $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$ and $\mu(\Omega) < \infty$, than we can write the Integral of $f$ wrt $\mu$ as
$$\int f d\mu  = \int f^+ d\mu - \int f^- d\mu 
=\int_{0}^{\infty} \mu \{y|f(y) \geq x\} dx + \int_{-\infty}^{0} [\mu \{y|f(y) \geq x\} - \mu(\Omega)] dx.  $$

I don't get how to derive the second part, i.e. where does the expression $\mu \{y|f(y) \geq x\} - \mu(\Omega)$ come from? (I know that this concerns the potentially negative part of the function, but at the moment I am unable to get, how I derive this second expression). Some help would be awesome!

Comment: Write $f = f_+ - f_-$. Also, you need to assume $\mu(\Omega) < \infty$ or else the second expression is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$ \mu( \{y \quad | \quad f(y) < x \}) + \mu (\{y \quad | \quad f(y) \ge x\} = \mu (\Omega)  $$

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I have now: $$ - \int f^- d\mu = - \int_0^{\infty} \mu( -f \geq x) dx = - \int_0^{\infty} \mu(f < -x) dx = \\  - \int_{-\infty}^0 \mu(f < x) dx = - \int_{- \infty}^0 [\mu(\Omega)- \mu(f \geq x) ]dx =  \int_{- \infty}^0 [ \mu(f \geq x)- \mu(\Omega) ]dx$$ Correct?

Comment: It's almost correct, you only need to justify the marked equality. $- \int_0^{\infty} \mu( -f \geq x) dx = - \int_0^{\infty} \mu(f  \color{red} \leq -x) dx =^{?} \int_0^{\infty} \mu(f  \color{red} < -x) dx $

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** In addition to @AsemAbdelraouf 's hint, apply Fubini's theorem to the integral
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb R}\int_{\Omega} \left(\mathbf{1}_{0\le x\le f(y)}-\mathbf{1}_{f(y)<x<0}\right) d x d\mu(y)
\end{equation}